# Need a simple clean 2013 theme

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, page-layout, design

Anybody have any recommendations for examples or sites that sell decent solutions?

I'm looking to replace the main page with page that looks similar to the tablet version of www.msn.com which I believe is t.msn.com.

We're looking for a simple jquery slider, video player and news feed in a simple clean layout with headers and layout similar to t.msn.com.

Any recommendations or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/

They offer lots of free as well as paid themes.

Here is the list of FAQ's http://bindtuning.com/faqs